# How use ASC/DESC inside a ORDER BY if statement?

Tags: mysql, sorting

The question is: "How can I order by a sql statement using an if value?"

I have a table in which I have a parameters and using this parameters I have to order by ASC or DESC a single column. How can I achieve it?

I have understood that the ASC and DESC parameters cannot be in a IF block (and have a structure like this one. "IF(Type = '1', ranking, ranking) ASC/DESC"), so which is the alternative to order inside a select in base to a parameters?

**EXAMPLE**

The table is something like:

```
ID | RANKING | TYPE
--------------------
1 | 12 | 1
2 | 10 | 1
3 | 14 | 2
4 | 15 | 2
```

The Type = 1 have to be an ASC order and the Type = 2 have to be a DESC order, so the expected result of my SELECT could be:

```
ID | RANKING | TYPE
--------------------
2 | 10 | 1
1 | 12 | 1
4 | 15 | 2
3 | 14 | 2
```

Any idea about it?

Comment: Do you mean you have a stored procedure with a parameter?  What does it look like?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ranking` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;


INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `ranking`, `type`) VALUES
(1, '12', 1),
(2, '10', 1),
(3, '14', 2),
(4, '15', 2);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about ordering by `IF(type=2, -ranking, ranking)` after ordering by type? Negating the ranking will cause the opposite order for that type.

**EDIT**

Since `ranking` is a `VARCHAR` column, you would need to to convert it to a number to use this technique.

```
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY type ASC, CAST(ranking as SIGNED)*IF(type = 1, 1, -1) ASC;
```

You can test the code directly at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/921cdb/1/0)

Comment: I've tried your solution, but it doesn't work... the result is the same with or without the -

Comment: SELECT * FROM `test` ORDER BY type ASC, IF(type = 1, ranking, -ranking) ASC. The result is 14/15 and not 15/14.

Comment: Odd. I just created a test table with the same data you posted and I got the expected results.

Comment: Using the same data and the same query posted by me above?

Comment: Whoops. I didn't notice `ranking` was `VARCHAR`. Sorry about that. Updating my answer now. Although is there any reason why you can't use an `INT`?

Comment: Because the ranking has data like "2:15.6", "4:31.12" and so on... I don't think that I could convert to a INT.

Comment: @Gabriele: I guess you know that with `varchar`, you'll get `11:15.6` ordered before `2:15.6`

Comment: @Gabriele Looks like this technique won't work for you then. Can you give more examples of the structure of `ranking` in your question?

Comment: I have solved using a CAST(ranking as DECIMAL(10,2))*IF(type = 1, 1,-1) ASC. So I have understand that the ORDER BY IF works only with number (INT, DECIMAL...). Great news, thanks a lot for your support!!!

Comment: You can test the code in the following direction at sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/921cdb/1/0

Answer (score 6):

```
ORDER BY type 
       , CASE WHEN type = 1
                THEN ranking 
              ELSE NULL               --- implied, this line can be omitted
                                      --- or changed into:   ELSE ''
                                      --- or:    ELSE someConstant
         END 
       , ranking DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you're getting at:  "... order inside a select in base to a parameters." - you accidentally a few words there.

But if this helps, you CAN order by multiple fields like this:

```
... ORDER BY type ASC, ranking DESC
```

and order by derived values:

```
... ORDER BY IF(ranking = 2, 1, 0) DESC, ranking ASC
```

which would place all the "ranking=2" records first, then any other ranking records ascending.

Comment: See the expected output. The order of ranking is conditional on the type.

Comment: Yes, the ranking column have to be use only as a condition for the "order by" and not for the order itself.